# Why is nil returned by Clojure functions that don't return a value?

Tags: clojure, null, functional-programming

I'm a new student of Clojure and don't get why "nil" is returned in REPL when I call functions that do not return values.

Above an example:

```
(println "Hello Nil")
nil
```

What type of evaluation process are made to reach "nil"?

Comment: *All* functions return a value. Clojure's idiom for  *nothing* is `nil`. So, when there's nothing to return, return `nil`. Many operators are set up to do this by default: `when`, one-sided `if`, `get`, `next`, ... . A function that *always* returns `nil`, such as `println`, must have significant side-effects to be useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a convention of functional languages like Clojure that every function needs to return exactly one value. For functions like `println` that are intended to perform side effects (like printing to the screen), it is not always clear what the return value could or should be.

In these cases, `nil` is a placeholder value that means "nothing" or "not applicable".

Comment: It is also a convention in Lisp to return useful values even when there are side-effects, and I don't understand why Clojure's print function cannot just return its argument; this is a detail but it helps if you just want to inspect the values of intermediate expressions. That being said, +1

Comment: For `println` it could return the string output to the screen, but for other functions like `doseq`, `dotimes`, etc it is not clear what a good return value should be.

Comment: I am specifically puzzled by how println works. In other cases nil is an acceptable value, I think we agree. There could be meaningful values with another approach, if you let `do...` macros accept a result form and provide an implicit block from which you can `return` a value ([`dotimes`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_dotime.htm)). But this is a different design and I understand that you are not supposed to return early in Clojure (lazy sequences, etc.).